# ViewController to NavigationController and back

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have one problem for which im not sure how to solve. Currently i have main `UIViewController` with some buttons. This is the initial view that is created with app. On it, one button calls storyboards segue with style Modal on ViewController which is part of `UINavigationController`. After that few other viewcontrollers are handled within the `UINavigationController` via segues and getting back via `navigationController:popViewControllerAnimated`. What i dont know is how to get back from `UINavigationController` to first `UIViewController`. I tried, when I'm on first one on navigationctrl,

```
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

yet that only removes the view but it seems that `UINavigationController` somehow stays alive as result is black screen. Creating unconnected segue and call it from code would be possibility, but im not sure if that is the proper way. Would that leave navigation controller alive ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using a `UIViewController` first and THEN a `UINavigationController`?

Why not change this so that the `UINavigationController` is the initial view controller and then drive everything from there.

If you want the first view to not have a nav bar then you can hide it easily.

That way you can move around through all views by popping and pushing through the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Hiding the bar should be a proper way. I was trying to hide it from IB but for some reason it still pops up. I will try to do it from code, but anyway im eiger to find out how to remove navcontroller :)

Comment: You can remove it from IB too. In the inspector for the view controller under "Simulated Metrics - Top Bar" select "None". You still haven't answered my question though. Why make it more difficult for yourself? Just stick the NavigationController as the Initial View Controller then you don't have to worry about removing it.

Comment: I agreed with you. I will use NavigationController. But i would like to learn how to remove navigationcontroller from window. Maybe at some other time i will need to...

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread it before :D Good question though. I suppose you'd have to remove it from the View Controller beneath it (i.e. the one that owns the nav controller). So you'd need some way (delegate method or something) to call back to it to tell it to remove the nag controller from itself.

Comment: Btw, i have put Top Bar to none, and in IB nav bar is hidden, but when app is started it pops up.

Comment: Yeah, you still have to hide the actual nav bar in code. In the viewWillAppear code put... `[self setNavigationBarHidden:YES]`